# Different styling when enumerating (with each_with_index)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm displaying a user top-5 ranking on my home page, with each_with_index.
I only manage to apply one global style to the 5 ranks.

```
<% @users_by_roi.take(5).each_with_index do |user, index| %>
  <div><class="ranking"> <%= index + 1 %></div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <%= link_to (image_tag user.picture.url(:medium), class: "small-avatar"), user_path(user) %>
  </div>
  <div><%= link_to "#{user.username}", user_path(user), class: "hot-tipster-link" %></div>
  <div class="green-roi"> + <%= user.roi.round(2) %> %</div>
<% end %>
```

How is it possible to apply specific styles to ranks 1, 2 and 3 (gold, silver, bronze) ?

Thank you

Comment: Like `<div class="ranking rank-1">1</div>`, `<div class="ranking rank-2">2</div>` etc?

Answer (score 1):

Actually in my humble opinion the best way to do this is in your css, as it is styling information and has nothing to do with the data you are showing in general.

To do this I would encourage you to check out the [n-th master](http://nthmaster.com/) site, it is a great reference for this. Here is a demo for a markup like yours:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper > div {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  height: 25px;
  width: 500px;
}

.wrapper > div:first-child {
  background-color: gold;
}

.wrapper > div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: silver;
}

.wrapper > div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>1. </div>
  <div>2. </div>
  <div>3. </div>
  <div>4. </div>
  <div>5. </div>
</div>
```